# WinRT WebView NavigateToString bug

Tags: c#, webview, navigation, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a strange problem with the `WebView` component in WinRT. I use it to display either a Website via `Soure property binding` or local content with `NavigateToString`.

**My problem is the following:**
If I change the `Source property`, it naviagtes to the Website. Then, I call `NavigateToString` and it displays the content correctly. After that I change the `Source property` again, but navigation doesn't start and the local content remains present.

Also if I first call `NavigateToString` and then change `Source property`, no navigation starts.

I prepared a small sample project to illustrate my problem: http://1drv.ms/1HI8p3I

### EDIT:

I updated the sample project above. I tried to call `Naviagte` via an `Attached Property` instead of changing the `Source property` but I got the same issue. Once I call `NavigateToString`, all other updates of `bindings` don't work.

This is my class with the Attached properties for WebView:

```
public class WebViewEx
{
    #region ContentString

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ContentString", typeof(string), typeof(WebViewEx), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnContentStringPropertyChanged)));

    public static void SetContentString(DependencyObject obj, string contentString)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ContentStringProperty, contentString);
    }

    public static string GetContentString(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ContentStringProperty);
    }

    private static void OnContentStringPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView webView = d as WebView;

        if (webView != null)
        {
            webView.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region UriString

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UriStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UriString", typeof(string), typeof(WebViewEx), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUriStringPropertyChanged)));

    public static void SetUriString(DependencyObject obj, string uriString)
    {
        obj.SetValue(UriStringProperty, uriString);
    }

    public static string GetUriString(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(UriStringProperty);
    }

    private static void OnUriStringPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView webView = d as WebView;

        if (webView != null)
        {
            webView.Navigate(new Uri((string)e.NewValue));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you just call `Navigate` rather than set the `Source` property?

Comment: If I call `Navigate` or `NavigateToString` manually, it works but if I call them via an `attached property` it does not work.